# How to enable an F# type-provider when running Visual Studio under windows user-account

Tags: f#, type-providers, websharper

Is it possible to run the [WebSharper](http://websharper.com/)'s UI.Next type provider (or any F# type provider) when running Visual Studio under a Windows user account?

I find that while running Windows under a user account (as strongly recommended in the [Zero Admins – Zero Problems](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK2335) Microsoft Ignite session), I have to run Visual Studio as an administrator or the [UI.Next](http://websharper.com/docs/ui.next) type provider doesn’t run (on my Windows 10 machine) and I get compile time errors.

Comment: I was eventually able to get this work after a lot of hacking. But I'm not really sure what did the trick. It's nice to know that it is possible to run type providers while logged in using a windows user account. Previously, as an F# newbie, I wasn't sure about that.